# Replace every <br/> with a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Google maps to generate different locations off of a variable I'm passing in. However, I get an error from the API saying it cannot find the address and I think I know why. It's because I have a `<br/>` tag for the variable that is being outputted.

**So for example when I alert the variable that's being passed through, it looks like this:**

Deep Forest`<br/>`Suite 233`<br/>`100 Top Lane`<br/>`Los Angeles, CA

**But I want the outputted variable to look like this.**

Deep Forest Suite 233 100 Top Lane Los Angeles, CA

In short, I just want to replace all instances of `<br/>` with a empty space. I have all my different location variables laid out like this.

Here is what I tried:

```
var content = ("cookie.current.addressLabel"); // this outputs the current location address which is Deep Forest<br/>Suite 233<br/>100 Top Lane<br/>Los Angeles, CA 
         var text = $(content).text();
        //showGoogleMap(content);
        var regPat = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: `text()` is going to strip out the HTML, if you want the `<br/>` tags in there so you can replace them you need to use `.html()`

Comment: @AndréDion Although this may be a duplicate the marked duplicate is not right.  This is an html() and regex question.  Regular text matching wouldn't be cross browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var content = ("cookie.current.addressLabel"); // this outputs the current location address which is Deep Forest<br/>Suite 233<br/>100 Top Lane<br/>Los Angeles, CA 
         var html= $(content).html();
        //showGoogleMap(content);
        html.replace( /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple replace should do the trick. No need for regex.

```
text.replace('<br/>', ' ');
```

Comment: technically browsers render <br> differently this isn't right as is plus he used .text instead .html